# Hide a pivot table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

How can I hide a pivot-table with VBA?

I tried accessing:

`.PivotTables(index).Visible`

But there is no `Visible` property for the `PivotTable` object.

I need to hide these pivot-tables if the user changes some check-boxes. Maybe I can hide them behind a white box, but in my opinion, this isn't a good solution.

If you can't help me, then I would do it with the white box.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.PivotTables(index).TableRange2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

This will hide all the rows in the pivot table

You could also achieve this by hiding columns

```
.PivotTables(index).TableRange2.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Comment: .EntireRow deleted the other pivot tables too, but .EntireColumn worked! Thanks, you helped me a lot :)

Comment: It doesn't delete them it will just hide them as you can only apply the property to the entire row or column, so which one you use is dependent on your sheet layout. Glad I could help :)