# How can I hide chosen pivot columns in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

In Excel 2013 I am trying to create a PivotTable that will present only the columns that are not empty (without null/zero) - 'Cel DS' doesn't have history, so I don't want to present it.

However, I don't want to delete 'Cel DS' entirely, because there is data in the second column under the heading 'bieżący'. Furtheromore, I can't delete the whole history because I have different column 'suma z wartość' which I want to show.

Is it possible to hide only columns that are marked with red arrows ?

[image: screenshot]
[(larger image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh5Pu.png)

Comment: Yes - have a look at this question from yesterday [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717516/hide-a-pivot-table-with-vba/40718094#40718094) You will also need to change the reference [link2](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=154:referencing-an-excel-pivot-table-range-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475) If you're still having issues update your question with what you have tried. SO is not a code writing service